# how to Check dir if file exists?

Tags: java, android, file

im developing an application which downloads images to an user phones.the download part works properly and the images are stored in **"/Android/data//files/".** I first do a check to see if the file exists,if not then i want to download it. but when i run the app it keep throwing a `NullpointerException`.is it because the **"/Android/data//files/"** doesn't exist during the first run time?if so how do i resolve this issue.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    testtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testtv);
    String imagename = "/img11.png";
    File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Android/data/com.id.imagedownloader/files" + imagename);
    // testtv.setText(image.toString());

    if (image.exists()) {
        testtv.setText("file exists");
    } else {
        Boolean result = isDownloadManagerAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (result) {
            downloadFile(imagename);
        }
    }

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void downloadFile(String imagename) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String DownloadUrl = "http://testing16.comlu.com/images/" + imagename;
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse(DownloadUrl));
    request.setDescription("sample file for testing"); // appears the same
                                                        // in Notification
                                                        // bar while
                                                        // downloading
    request.setTitle("Test Title");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    String fileName = DownloadUrl.substring(
            DownloadUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, DownloadUrl.length());
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), null,
            fileName);

    // get download service and enqueue file
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);

}

public static boolean isDownloadManagerAvailable(Context context) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setClassName("com.android.providers.downloads.ui",
                "com.android.providers.downloads.ui.DownloadList");
        List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(intent,
                        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.id.imagedownloader/com.id.imagedownloader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:441)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationFromBase(DownloadManager.java:504)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadManager.java:466)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.id.imagedownloader.MainActivity.downloadFile(MainActivity.java:63)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.id.imagedownloader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
11-03 14:13:35.821: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Maybe `try {...} catch (IOException e) {...}`

Comment: Isnt the exception coming from the method downloadFile? com.id.imagedownloader.MainActivity.downloadFile(MainActivity.java:63), so if you set the destination in the external storage, make sure the folder exists, then this should work (at least from what I see)

Comment: Its not gurantees that th external storage exists

Comment: Maybe you forgot to acquire permission to access external storage?
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: @wns349 i did add that permission when testing the download function

Comment: I just tested my code on my GS3 running CM11 and it works fine..it only crashes in the emulator.why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,image);
```

dont forget to create dirs with mkdirs() if parent folder are not exist

Answer (score 0):

`setDestinationInExternalFilesDir` requires dirType parameter. You should use it like :

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
        fileName);
```

Answer (score -1):

With this function you can create a file from byte array and check if this exist. Try something like this:

```
/**
 * Create new file from byte array
 * @param path  
 * @param array source
 * @throws IOException  
 */
public static void writeFile(String path, byte[] array) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    if (!file.exists() && array != null) {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        bos.write(array);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } else {
        // the file exists...

    }
}
```

Hope it help you!!

Comment: I just tested my code on my GS3 running CM11 and it works fine..it only crashes in the emulator.why is that?

Comment: If you try save the file in external storage it is possible that crashes for it.

Comment: Can you add the logcat trace?